# Transposing row from Excel into a Word Document Table

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, transpose

I have a database in Excel, each entry runs horizontally for 8 cells (A2:H10 for example).
I am trying to create Word documents enmasse from each 8 cell entry that inject vertically into a Word document table that is 8 cells total.

Here is an example of the code I have tried.

```vb
Sub CreateEntry()

Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wd As Object
Dim myarray As Variant

On Error Resume Next
Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Set wd = wdApp.Documents.Add

wdApp.Visible = True

Sheets("Accommodation").Activate
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:E76")
myarray = Range("A2:H2")
Range("A2:H2").Value = myarray
Range("A40:A48").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myarray)
Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A40:A48")

Rng.Copy

With wd.Range
    .Collapse Direction:=0
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    .Collapse Direction:=0
    .PasteSpecial False, False, True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried mailmerge? No code required. Simply create a mailmerge main document with the table layout you require and mergefields in each row pointing to the data fields (column headings) in Excel. For the basics, see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

Answer (score 0):

You can create tables directly in Word using the Word object model.  That gives you more control over how it turns out.

```vb
Sub CreateEntry()

    Dim doc As Object, rw As Range, tbl As Object
    Dim n As Long
    
    For Each rw In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Accommodation").Range("A2:H3").Rows
        Set doc = GetWordDoc()
        Set tbl = doc.tables.Add(doc.Range, rw.Cells.Count, 1)
        For n = 1 To rw.Cells.Count
            tbl.Cell(n, 1).Range.Text = rw.Cells(n).Text
        Next n
    Next rw

End Sub

Function GetWordDoc() As Object
    Dim wdApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wdApp.Visible = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set GetWordDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add
End Function
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you to both of you for your time. I will try both. Mail-merge sounds  wonderfully simple. Thank you again guys!